# Flicker-free drawable ScrolledWindow

Tags: python, wxpython, flicker, scrolledwindow

I'm trying to build a ScrolledWindow that you can draw on using the mouse, and it's working too, but I'm getting a nasty flicker when the user is drawing on the window while the scrollbars aren't in the "home" position..

To reproduce, run the attached program, scroll a bit down (or to the right) and "doodle" a bit by keeping the left mouse button pressed. You should see a flickering now and then..

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """ Just a frame with a DrawPane """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        s = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        s.Add(DrawPane(self), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(s)

########################################################################
class DrawPane(wx.PyScrolledWindow):
    """ A PyScrolledWindow with a 1000x1000 drawable area """

    VSIZE = (1000, 1000)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        wx.PyScrolledWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.SetScrollbars(10, 10, 100, 100)
        self.prepare_buffer()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_mouse_down)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.on_motion)

    def prepare_buffer(self):
        self.buffer = wx.EmptyBitmap(*DrawPane.VSIZE)
        dc = wx.BufferedDC(None, self.buffer)
        dc.Clear()
        dc.DrawLine(0, 0, 999, 999) # Draw something to better show the flicker problem

    def on_paint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self, self.buffer, wx.BUFFER_VIRTUAL_AREA)

    def on_mouse_down(self, evt):
        self.mouse_pos = self.CalcUnscrolledPosition(evt.GetPosition()).Get()

    def on_motion(self, evt):
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            dc = wx.BufferedDC(wx.ClientDC(self), self.buffer)
            newpos = self.CalcUnscrolledPosition(evt.GetPosition()).Get()
            coords = self.mouse_pos + newpos
            dc.DrawLine(*coords)
            self.mouse_pos = newpos
            self.Refresh()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    MainFrame(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I tried using `SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)`, or binding `EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND`, or using `RefreshRect` instead of `Refresh`, but the flicker is still there.. Any idea on what I might try next?

My environment: Xubuntu 9.04, wxPython 2.8.9.1
(but tested on Ubuntu 10.04 too)

Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Robin Dunn himself:

> First, a `Refresh()` by default will
>   erase the background before sending
>   the paint event (although setting the
>   BG style or catching the erase event
>   would have taken care of that.)  The
>   second and probably most visible
>   problem in this case is that in your
>   `on_motion` handler you are not
>   offsetting the ClientDC by the scroll
>   offsets, just the position in the
>   buffer that you are drawing the line
>   segment at.  So when the buffer is
>   flushed out to the client DC it is
>   drawn at the physical (0,0), not the
>   virtual (0,0).  In other words, the
>   flicker you are seeing is coming from
>   drawing the buffer at the wrong
>   position after every mouse drag event,
>   and then it immediately being drawn
>   again at the right position in the
>   `on_paint` triggered by the
>   `Refresh()`.
>
> You should be able to fix this by
>   calling `PrepareDC` on the client DC
>   before using it, like this:
>
> ```
>     cdc = wx.CLientDC(self)
>     self.PrepareDC(cdc)
>     dc = wx.BufferedDC(cdc, self.buffer)
> ```
>
> However since you are doing a
>   `Refresh` or `RefreshRect` anyway,
>   there is no need to use a client DC
>   here at all, just let the flushing of
>   the buffer to the screen be done in
>   on_paint instead:
>
> ```
>     dc = wx.BufferedDC(None, self.buffer)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Using Joril recomendations and removing Refresh(), there is no flicker anymore (even enlarging the frame).

```
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """ Just a frame with a DrawPane """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        s = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        s.Add(DrawPane(self), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(s)

########################################################################
class DrawPane(wx.PyScrolledWindow):
    """ A PyScrolledWindow with a 1000x1000 drawable area """

    VSIZE = (1000, 1000)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        wx.PyScrolledWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.SetScrollbars(10, 10, 100, 100)
        self.prepare_buffer()
        cdc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        self.PrepareDC(cdc)
        dc = wx.BufferedDC(cdc, self.buffer)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_mouse_down)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.on_motion)

    def prepare_buffer(self):
        self.buffer = wx.EmptyBitmap(*DrawPane.VSIZE)
        cdc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        self.PrepareDC(cdc)
        dc = wx.BufferedDC(cdc, self.buffer)
        dc.Clear()
        dc.DrawLine(0, 0, 999, 999) # Draw something to better show the flicker problem


    def on_paint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self, self.buffer, wx.BUFFER_VIRTUAL_AREA)

    def on_mouse_down(self, evt):
        self.mouse_pos = self.CalcUnscrolledPosition(evt.GetPosition()).Get()

    def on_motion(self, evt):
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            newpos = self.CalcUnscrolledPosition(evt.GetPosition()).Get()
            coords = self.mouse_pos + newpos
            cdc = wx.ClientDC(self)
            self.PrepareDC(cdc)
            dc = wx.BufferedDC(cdc, self.buffer)
            dc.DrawLine(*coords)
            self.mouse_pos = newpos

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    MainFrame(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```